# Select all font-awesome icons

Tags: css, font-awesome

I'm trying to make a navigation bar with bootstrap on ruby on rails using haml. I am making the nav bar responsive, using the hamburger menu. When the browser is smaller than 1040px, I'd like to make all the icons larger. Is there a way to select all the icons, or do I have to manually select all of the icons?

Here is the code (application.html.haml):

```
%body
    %header
        %nav.navbar.navbar-fixed-top{role: "navigation"}
            .mobile
                %div.navbar-brand
                    %i.fa.fa-bars.bars{"data-target" => ".navbar-collapse", "data-toggle" => "collapse", type: "button"}
                    = link_to "Recipeazy", root_path, style: "color: #696969;"

            .collapse.navbar-collapse.navbar-collapse
                %ul.navbar-nav.navbar-right
                    .navbar-items
                        - if user_signed_in?
                            %li.nav-item
                                = link_to "Home", root_path
                                %i.fa.fa-home
                            %li.nav-item
                                = link_to "About", about_path
                                %i.fa.fa-info-circle
                            %li.nav-item
                                = link_to "Settings", edit_user_registration_path
                                %i.fa.fa-cog
                            %li.nav-item
                                = link_to "New", new_post_path
                                %i.fa.fa-plus-circle
                            %li.nav-item
                                = link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
                                %i.fa.fa-sign-out
                        - else
                            %li.nav-item
                                = link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path
                                %i.fa.fa-sign-in
                            %li.nav-item
                                = link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path
                                %i.fa.fa-user-plus
```

Comment: Please show some codes because this question depends on your markup.

Comment: Ok, I've added it. I'm using SASS (I believe) since all my css is in a `.css.scss` file.

Comment: You could use something like `li.nav-item i {font-size: ... }` to edit the icons.

Comment: I did `.fa {font-size:20px;}` however I inspected the website and it says the font-awesome code has priority therefor the code I put in does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer.

Basically you just add the class of the size you want the icon to be. You can find the sizes [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/sizing-icons).